# How to make the page title display from the web form when the Master Page already has a title?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

When I render default.apsx the page title in the browser tab is taken from the Master Page and I want it to be taken from default.aspx

This is default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

            <title>Default.aspx Page Title</title>

    </asp:Content>
```

This is the Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Master Page Title</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Title = "foo" in code beside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends, you can hard-code the current aspx page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "new page title";
}
```

Or you can get the title from another source, like the Web.sitemap file.

If you want to get it from something on the page, the title has to be in a control with `runat="server"`, so you can get the value from code-behind.